# Error Inflating New Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-intent

**Summary**: MainActivityFragment passes passes an intent to DetailedActivity when an item is clicked to display detailed data. Since I want to display these within a Two-Pane interface, I needed to make the DetailedActivity a fragment.

**Problem** : Whenever clicking on the item in MainActivityFragment to launch the intent for DetailedActivityFragment, I get an error saying its unable to start or inflate the activity. The detailedActivity for sake here is named "test" and "testFragment". It appears as though it points to line 25 of the activity_test.xml which is the line of include layout="@...".

I have left the fragment_test.xml out due to its length but i will provide a github link to anyone whom may want to see it or the manifest.

Im currently a novice to the android world so any help is appriciated =)! This branch of my project is a huge mess right now experimenting with things right now so pardon the mess...

**Github Link:**https://github.com/Rykuno/Flix-Viewer/tree/tablet/app/src/main/java/com/rykuno/movietestapp/Activities

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.rykuno.movietestapp, PID: 14281
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rykuno.movietestapp/com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
                                                                             at com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.test.onCreate(test.java:14)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                             at com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.test.onCreate(test.java:14) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                                             at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                                                                             at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                                                                             at com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.testFragment.setViewData(testFragment.java:100)
                                                                             at com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.testFragment.onCreateView(testFragment.java:87)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                             at com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.test.onCreate(test.java:14) 
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the code to the Activity Files vvv

```
package com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.rykuno.movietestapp.R;

public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

}
```

And the fragment

```
package com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.rykuno.movietestapp.Adapter.TrailerAdapter;
import com.rykuno.movietestapp.BuildConfig;
import com.rykuno.movietestapp.Data.DatabaseHelper;
import com.rykuno.movietestapp.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class testFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String MOVIEKEYS = "videoKeys";
    private String movieVideoUrl;
    private List<String> movieKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    private String mPoster;
    private String mOriginalTitle;
    private String mPlot;
    private String mReleaseDate;
    private String mBackDrop;
    private String mRating;
    private boolean mFavorited = false;
    private int mId;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private TrailerAdapter mTrailerAdapter;
    @Bind(R.id.title_textView)
    TextView mTitleTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.rating_textView)
    TextView mRatingTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.plot_textView)
    TextView mPlotTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.backdrop_image)
    ImageView mBackdropImageView;
    @Bind(R.id.poster_imageView)
    ImageView mPosterImageView;
    @Bind(R.id.released_textView)
    TextView mReleaseDateTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.comments_button)
    Button mCommentsButton;
    @Bind(R.id.favorite_imageView)
    ImageView mFavoritesImageView;
    @Bind(R.id.trailer_gridview)
    GridView mGridView;

    public testFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());
        extractExtras();
        setViewData();
        getMovieYoutubeHandle();
        setClickItems();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void setViewData() {
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/" + mBackDrop).into(mBackdropImageView);
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/" + mPoster).into(mPosterImageView);
        mTitleTextView.setText(mOriginalTitle);
        mRatingTextView.setText(mRating + "/10");
        mPlotTextView.setText(mPlot);
        mReleaseDateTextView.setText(mReleaseDate);

    }

    private void extractExtras() {
        mPoster = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("poster");
        mOriginalTitle = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        mPlot = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("plot");
        mReleaseDate = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("releaseDate");
        mBackDrop = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("backdrop");
        mRating = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("rating");
        mId = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
        mFavorited = getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra("favorited", false);

    }

    private void getMovieYoutubeHandle(){
        movieVideoUrl = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+mId+"/videos?api_key="+ BuildConfig.MY_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY;
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(movieVideoUrl).build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                try {
                    movieKeys = Arrays.asList(getTrailerData(jsonData));
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTrailerAdapter.setListData(movieKeys);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private String[] getTrailerData(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject trailerDetails = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray results = trailerDetails.getJSONArray("results");
        String[] keyArray = new String[results.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i<results.length(); i++){
            JSONObject keyResults = results.getJSONObject(i);
            String youtubeKey = keyResults.getString("key");
            keyArray[i] = youtubeKey;
        }
        return keyArray;
    }

    private void setClickItems() {
        //initializes gridview for trailers and onItemClicks
        mTrailerAdapter = new TrailerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.trailer_item, movieKeys);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mTrailerAdapter);
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String keyPosition = movieKeys.get(position).toString();
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + keyPosition)));
            }
        });

        //onClick launches the CommentsActivity
        mCommentsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CommentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //onClick for favorites
        mFavoritesImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                boolean isInserted = db.insertData(getActivity(), mId, mOriginalTitle, mPlot, mBackDrop, mPoster, mRating, mReleaseDate);
                if (isInserted = true) {
                    mFavoritesImageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
                    Log.v(DetailedMovie.class.getSimpleName(), "entry worked");
                } else if (isInserted = false) {
                    Log.v(DetailedMovie.class.getSimpleName(), "entry failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        ArrayList<String> toSave = movieKeys instanceof ArrayList ?
                (ArrayList<String>) movieKeys : new ArrayList<>(movieKeys);
        outState.putStringArrayList(MOVIEKEYS, toSave);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

As well as the layout files.

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.test">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_test"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_test.xml

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1"
          android:name="com.rykuno.movietestapp.Activities.testFragment"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"/>
```

Comment: Please provide only relevant code and log details. Complete code with import statements and full log is not needed. No one is gong to read this all. Edit your question and give us only the code relevant to your question of Fragment launch.

Comment: post `R.layout.fragment_test`

Comment: @VarunKumar I feel as though the import statements are important in this case no? And not really sure what to cut down on the log considering im not exactly sure where or what went wrong.

Comment: @MML13 here you go mate! https://github.com/Rykuno/Flix-Viewer/blob/tablet/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_test.xml

Comment: @Rykuno add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the begining of `R.layout.fragment_test`

Comment: Solved! To anyone in the future whom may have this problem and is using an injection view such as butterknife, the butterknife.bind() method required ButterKnife.bind(this,rootView) instead of the getActivity so it wasnt loading any layout.

Answer (score 1):

**make sure to use:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

And also make sure that the Activity that is using the **fragment(s) extends FragmentActivity instead of the regular Activity,**

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

to get the **FragmentActivity class.**

Comment: add this to the test or the fragment class?

Comment: **public class test extends FragmentActivity**

Comment: post complete code of **content_test.xml** if it is complete code then add this above yur fragment tag **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>**

Comment: I got it solved my friend, turns out it was my butterknife injection! I appriciate the input on the use of fragment Activity though

Answer (score 1):

One think I found is add `app:layout_behaviour` to include tag and not inside `content_test.xml`

```
 <include  layout="@layout/content_test"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
```

And your project got many NPE unable to test more.

Comment: thanks for the input man! I finally was able to debug what it was though! The butterknife.bind() method required ButterKnife.bind(this,rootView) instead of the getActivity so it wasnt loading any layout.